# Pandas one-liner to join series elements

Tags: python, pandas

I was playing with pandas methods and encountered an issue.
Can I join the elements of pandas series with comma?

## MWE

```py
j = {
  "locations": [
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
  ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(j['locations'])
ans = df.query("state=='WA'")['name'].sort_values()[-2:]

ans = df.query("state=='WA'")['name'].sort_values()[-2:].pipe(str.join) # this is my attempt but it does not work
```

## Required answer

```
'Olympia, Seattle'

# NOTE:
obviously I can do ', '.join(ser.values)
but I am looking for pipe method.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
j = {
  "locations": [
    {"name": "Seattle", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "New York", "state": "NY"},
    {"name": "Bellevue", "state": "WA"},
    {"name": "Olympia", "state": "WA"}
  ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(j['locations'])

ans = df.query("state=='WA'")['name'].sort_values()[-2:]
ans.pipe(', '.join)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to pipe `join` into data frame, but `str.join` the full dataframe instead:

```py
ans = ', '.join(df.query("state=='WA'")['name'].sort_values().iloc[-2:].tolist())
```

Additionally - using `iloc[-2:]` instead of just `[-2:]` will be safer, cause you won't be relying then on index being numbers `0, 1, 2, 3, ...`.